# value is not changing of session array to json array via ajax

Tags: php, json, session

I have a session array **$_SESSION['Cartquantity']** . In **php** file on line no **200** I am storing this array in a variable  **$QtyArray**

```
$QtyArray = $_SESSION['Cartquantity'] ;
```

then I am encoding the array in  **json** to use it on **js** file

```
echo "var cartQty = " . json_encode($QtyArray) . ";" ; (on line 201)
```

Now via the **AJAX** I am updating the session array on line no **120** in the same way

```
$QtyArray = $_SESSION['Cartquantity'] ;                (on line 120)
echo "var cartQty = " . json_encode($QtyArray) . ";" ; (on line 121)
```

array is clearly updating because I can see this on console of firebug. But when I am getting this value on js file value is not changing. While if I reload the page where I update this value via ajax and then go to view quantity it is changing. Why is that happening ?

Please help!!!

Comment: Are you generating your `js` file by using this PHP script? If so, only when the browser requests the file again (i.e. if you reload the page, and the file is not in cache) that you'll see the changes. Is that what's happening, or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you disable caching in your ajax call, like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   cache: false  //DISABLE CACHING
}).done(function( html ) {
   $("#results").append(html);
});
```

**UPDATE:**
Here your `.get()` call adapted for `.ajax()` with cache option :

```
$.ajax({
   url: "index.php",
   data: { q: "add_card", item_id: id, item_qty: qty, topping_extra_v: topping_extra_val,item_syskey:syskey },
   cache: false  //DISABLE CACHING
}).done(function( data ) {
   alert(data);
});
```

Comment: I am also passing some values like `$.get("index.php", { q: "add_card", item_id: id, item_qty: qty, topping_extra_v: topping_extra_val,item_syskey:syskey },function(data){});

Now where I will add cache:false

Comment: @Shreya [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is a shorthand to `$.ajax`, with some default parameters (see linked docs). I think you'll have to rewrite your request using the latter function.

Comment: ok now let's say I have this code $.ajax("index.php", { q: "add_card", item_id: id, item_qty: qty, topping_extra_v: topping_extra_val,item_syskey:syskey },function(data){});

Now where I will add cache:false . I am doing like this but giving error $.ajax("index.php",cache:false, { q: "add_card", item_id: id, item_qty: qty, topping_extra_v: topping_extra_val,item_syskey:syskey },function(data){});

Comment: See my updated answer for a `.ajax()` version of your `.get()` call, with caching disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo "var cartQty = " . json_encode($QtyArray) . ";" ;// (on line 121)
```

to

```
echo json_encode($QtyArray);
```

then make your ajax call like this

```
$.ajax({
    url:"index.php",
    cache:false, 
    dataType:'json',
    data:{ q: "add_card", item_id: id, item_qty: qty, topping_extra_v: topping_extra_val,item_syskey:syskey },
    function(data){
        cartQty = data;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Shreya are you getting any errors, do you have any more output for the ajax call other than line 121

Comment: @Mussa see I am clicking on + icon and updating the session array via ajax. Now I am clicking on submit button and displaying results via the javascript using fadein() method. When I was updating the value it is clearly changing because I can see the result in firebug but when I go after submit and see results on web page it's not seems to change while before clicking on submit button if I reload the page then click on submit button then value gets change. I hope u got my point.

Comment: @Shreya you're going to have to actually modify your page to represent the changes in `cartQty`